# reflection get value from all types in DLL

Tags: c#, reflection

I'm trying to load a DLL and for each type, display the property names and values. I have the following code, which throws a System.Reflection.TargetException with the message "Object does not match target type".

```
var DLL = Assembly.LoadFrom(PathToDLL);
                foreach (Type type in DLL.GetTypes())
                {
                    foreach (PropertyInfo property in type.GetProperties())
                    {
                        lstProperties.Items.Add(string.Format("{0} - {1}", property.Name, property.GetValue(DLL, null)));
                    }
                }
```

I've tried using type, DLL and null with the GetValue() call, What am I doing wrong?

The DLL I'm testing against has one property:

```
public string TheValue{ get; set; }
```

thanks all.

Comment: You need an instance of the type to get the value of an instance property.

Comment: You can't display a value of a **class** property, there isn't one. You can only display the value of an **object** property. This is where the difference between class and object is important.

Comment: Of course, there can be types in an assembly that you cannot instantiate (abstract classes come to mind). And you should think twice before instantiating all the types you can, that's basically running arbitrary code you do not control (then again, so does loading arbitrary assemblies).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding on the comments, here is an example of what they are talking about.

In the DLL:

```
public class TheClass
{
    public string TheValue { get; set; }
}
```

Create an instance of the class and set the property value:

```
TheClass cls = new TheClass();
cls.TheValue = "hello!";
```

Then change your code to refer to the instance you created:

```
lstProperties.Add(string.Format("{0} - {1}", property.Name, property.GetValue(cls, null)));
```